# Jquery UI autocomplete wont work for searching name with id

Tags: php, jquery

I am using autocomplete for searching name and get id based on name. It works but when I select name, I am getting id only and also name field is overwritten by id.

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#search_name').autocomplete({
        source: 'office_result_search.php',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("#search_name").val(ui.item.label); // display the selected text
            $("#hdnId").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input
        }
    });

</script>
```

office_result_search.php coding

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM admit WHERE name LIKE '%{$searchTerm}%'");
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $array[] = array (

            'label' => $row['name'],
            'value' => $row['id']

        );
    }
    echo json_encode ($array);
?>
```

Html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_name" name="name" placeholder="Search By Name">
    </div>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hdnId" name="hdnId">
```

Comment: In real life scenario, how you will remember every id to search, the search should allow any regex and you need to search that in your table(s).

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu are you getting my problem? I am searching name, and next input field get id of specific name. but when i enter in name field,both field refresh with id .

Comment: Are you trying to get id, using name?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu yes

Comment: 2 things, first why you  are using `mysql_*` functions, those are removed now and you should not use them, if you want to return id, why you are selecting `*` change those two things and `var_dump` the result you are getting from query or print the final query and run in phpmyadmin/sql console .

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should upgrade to prepared statements as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return false;` in your script `$("#hdnId").val(ui.item.value); // save selected id to hidden input`and try!